# FormGroup async validator not working properly

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I can't figure out why my async validator doesn't work properly with **FormGroup**.
I have: model class

**address.model.ts**

```
export interface Address {
  city: string;
  street: string;
}
```

Component that has form and predefined addresses

**some.component.ts**

```
addressForm: FormGroup;
addresses: Address[] = [
        {city: 'LA', street: 'Pushkina'},
        {city: 'NY', street: 'Shmidta'}
      ];
```

...

```
ngOnInit() {
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      address: new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        street: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      }, null, this.availableDeliveryAddresses.bind(this))});
}
```

And async validator defined in this component

```
availableDeliveryAddresses(formGroup: FormGroup): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.addresses.indexOf({city: formGroup.controls['city'].value, street: formGroup.controls['street'].value}) === -1)  {
          resolve({'noAddress': true});
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1500);
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

In template I have

**some.component.html**

```
    <div>
              <label for="city">City</label>
              <small *ngIf="!addressForm.get('address.city').valid && addressForm.get('address.city').touched">
                City is required
              </small>
              <small *ngIf="addressForm.get('address.city').touched &&
              addressForm.get('address.street').touched &&
   addressForm.hasError('noAddress', ['address'])">Given address is not our delivery scope</small>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" formControlName="city">
    </div>
```

And in each case I receive "Given address is not our delivery scope" message.

Comment: indexOf() tests if the array contains the argument. But it doesn't: your argument, even if it has the same properties, is a different object from the ones stored in the array. They are compared with `===`, and `{ foo: 'bar' } === { foo: 'bar' }` is false.

Comment: Rather that using `indexOf`, consider using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Comment: @R.Richards some() (or its reverse, every()) would actually be more approriate, since the index doesn't matter.

Comment: @JBNizet I though about that for a second after I posted the comment. All sorts of options in the scenario.

Comment: @JBNizet, I changed code to that
if (this.addresses.some(el => el === {
          city: formGroup.controls['city'].value,
          street: formGroup.controls['street'].value
        })) {
          resolve(null);
        } else {
          resolve({'noAddress': true});
        }
Also, I tried to use findIndex() instead(with === -1). But behavior is still the same :(

Comment: You're still comparing two objects with ===. That will only return true if the two variables reference the exact same object. You need to compare properties: `if (this.addresses.some(a => a.city ===  formGroupValue.city && a.street === formGroup.value.street))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, problem was in approach to comparing objects.
Comparing objects by === instead of comparing each property.